# Get Map values inside vf Component and in apex:repeat

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce, map

Hi have a `List<String>` Key and a `map<String, String>` mapkv

VF Page:

```
<apex:page applyHtmlTag="false" controller="testController" extensions="otherclass1" action="{!someFunction}"> 

<c:test lstkey="{!lstkey}" mapkv="{!mapkv}" /> 

</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
Public static List<String> Key {get;set;}
Public static map<String, String> mapkv {get;set;}
function(){
//Controller class is something like:
for(String s:lstStr){
Key.add(s);
mapkv.put(s,'abc');
} 
}
```

now on my component

I am passing the attribute as

```
<apex:attribute type="map" name="mapkv" description="Navigation HTML code" required="true" />
<apex:attribute type="String[]" name="lstkey" description="Navigation HTML code" />
```

and inside the component I want to use the map like:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!lstkey}" var="key" >
     <apex:repeat value="{!mapkv[key]}" var="item">
          <a href="{!item}"><span> {!key}</span></a>      
     </apex:repeat>                            
</apex:repeat>
```

but I am getting an error saying Syntax error: Found mapkv.

Please help me resolve this. How can I get the map value in the component so that it can be set as the href.

Comment: How are you provided value for mapkv and lstkey attributes in the component?

Comment: yes, I am passing the value to the component when its called from the page like:
<apex:page applyHtmlTag="false" controller="testController" extensions="otherclass1" action="{!someFunction}">
 <c:test lstkey="{!lstkey}" mapkv="{!mapkv}"  />
</apex:page>

Comment: can you post your VF page along with the apex:page tag?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the provided Component and Controller markup, I believe you are getting the error because you trying to iterate over a string value.
Looking at this

> < apex:repeat value="{!mapkv[key]}" var="item" >

Mapkv[key] will give you a string value and you cannot iterate over a string.
Your code should be something like.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!lstkey}" var="key" > 
<a href="{!mapkv[key]}"><span> {!key}</span></a>
 </apex:repeat>
```

Comment: how is your code any different than <a href="{!key}">{!key}</a> , I do not see any error with the way the op has structured his code

Comment: This code is correct. There is no need for two `<apex:repeat` tags. The repeat over `lstkey` gets the key as `key`. The `href` retrieves the value from the map using `key` and the `span` is around the key itself.

Comment: i just saw what the op did he was looping the key inside his second repeat. this answer is the right way to go :)

Comment: Yes rao, I agree with you however, this is a specific solution for the syntax error OP is recieving. I believe if OP was passing lstkey instead if key, he would have received a different error Ex. No such property controllername.lstkey , probably its an error while posting.

Comment: @manjit_singh : I tried the above code as well, and getting the same error.

Comment: I have tried o replicate this but I am able to save and run the code successfully. I have created a sample Controller, Component and a page based on your input. Please check. [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/rXDYy8t5)

Answer (score 0):

Check your component's API version. The API version must be greater that 19 to use Visualforce dynamic binding.